When debugging in VS Code, it doesn't take command inputs for Python
While debugging in VS Code, I am trying to give command lines but it doesn't take any and it moves directly to input(). Here len(sys.argv) is always equal to one.
I saw an old question which was exactly about the same, but it didn't help.
In watch it says len(sys.argv)=1 and it doesn't take any input


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

sys.argv is the name of your python script which you are running in VC Code. If your script does not contain any code with print statements, then there would be no ouput to view, and VS Code only confirms that it ran your python script that is the 1 value in sys.argv list

Add "args": ["arg1", "arg2", "arg3"] to your launch.json if you want to pass some values.
This configuration ensures that sys.argv will contain the specified arguments when your script runs in the debugger.
Read document about args for more details.

yup this solved it

@icecream Hi, if you find the solution, you could click '✔' to mark it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See also stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote
